Why does Entity Framework generate a "EmployeesProjects" when I migrate for a Many-to-Many Relationship? I've already defined another one?
I have two entities: Employeees and Projects which have the relationship of Many-to-Many. I defined a ProjectEmployee for that, but when I add migration, it still creates a EmployeesProjects. Why does this happen and how can I fix that? Thank you guys!
Here is the Employees.cs
using Day1.Model;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Employees
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinedDate { get; set; }
    public Salaries Salary { get; set; }
    public IList<Projects> Projects { get; set; }
    public Departments Department { get; set; }
    public IList<ProjectEmployee> ProjectEmployees { get; set; }
}

Projects.cs
using Day1.Model;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Projects
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Employees> Employees { get; set; }
    public IList<ProjectEmployee> ProjectEmployees { get; set; }
}

The ProjectEmployee.cs
namespace Day1.Model
{
    public class ProjectEmployee
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public Projects Project { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public Employees Employee { get; set; }
        public bool Enable { get; set; }
    }
}

Here is the migration:
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

#pragma warning disable CA1814 // Prefer jagged arrays over multidimensional

namespace Day1.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class InitialCreate : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Departments",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Departments", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Projects",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Projects", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Employees",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                    DepartmentId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    JoinedDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Employees", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Employees_Departments_DepartmentId",
                        column: x => x.DepartmentId,
                        principalTable: "Departments",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "EmployeesProjects",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    EmployeesId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    ProjectsId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_EmployeesProjects", x => new { x.EmployeesId, x.ProjectsId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_EmployeesProjects_Employees_EmployeesId",
                        column: x => x.EmployeesId,
                        principalTable: "Employees",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_EmployeesProjects_Projects_ProjectsId",
                        column: x => x.ProjectsId,
                        principalTable: "Projects",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "ProjectEmployees",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ProjectId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    EmployeeId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    Enable = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_ProjectEmployees", x => new { x.ProjectId, x.EmployeeId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_ProjectEmployees_Employees_EmployeeId",
                        column: x => x.EmployeeId,
                        principalTable: "Employees",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_ProjectEmployees_Projects_ProjectId",
                        column: x => x.ProjectId,
                        principalTable: "Projects",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Salaries",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    EmployeeId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    Salary = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Salaries", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Salaries_Employees_EmployeeId",
                        column: x => x.EmployeeId,
                        principalTable: "Employees",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "Departments",
                columns: new[] { "Id", "Name" },
                values: new object[,]
                {
                    { 1, "Software Development" },
                    { 2, "Finance" },
                    { 3, "Accountant" },
                    { 4, "HR" }
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Employees_DepartmentId",
                table: "Employees",
                column: "DepartmentId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_EmployeesProjects_ProjectsId",
                table: "EmployeesProjects",
                column: "ProjectsId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_ProjectEmployees_EmployeeId",
                table: "ProjectEmployees",
                column: "EmployeeId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Salaries_EmployeeId",
                table: "Salaries",
                column: "EmployeeId",
                unique: true);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "EmployeesProjects");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "ProjectEmployees");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Salaries");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Projects");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Employees");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Departments");
        }
    }
}

I tried manually deleting the EmployeesProjects table create code block in migration, but it would still generate it when I add migration. I searched every files to see if I configed the model anywhere, but the result wasn't so positive.

Why do you have two collections, Employees and ProjectEmployees, on class Projects? I think you only need Employees.

Since I have already defined the ProjectEmployee entity, there's no use to include
    public IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

in Employees.cs and
    public IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

in Projects.cs.
The system will automatically generate an entity to insert Many-To-Many relation, even when there has already been one.

This is correct, but to add some more context: a many-many relationship really a one-to-many relationship with an extra hidden table that manages the connection. In this case, the third table is not hidden, so the 2 one-to-many relationships is manually managed. Adding the extra lists actually tells EF to make a second many-to-many relationship on a seperate field.
